# WSO2 Api Manager fails to show user roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We recently upgraded from API Manager 1.90 to 1.10 using the instructions on the Wso2 website. When we load the carbon local admin console, most of the pages load just fine. However, when we load the user list, select a user and click either view or assign roles, this error occurs. I have not been able to find an issue tied to it on the JIRA boards. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

```
2016-08-23 09:26:05,638 [-] [http-nio-443-exec-2] ERROR JspTilesRequestContext JSPException while including path '/user/edit-user-roles.jsp'. 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.

Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.user.edit_002duser_002droles_jsp

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.user.edit_002duser_002droles_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
```

Comment: it´s a fresh 1.10 APIM?

Comment: @JorgeInfanteOsorio yes, code wise it is a fresh install. the DB migrated from 1.9 to 1.10 following the instructions in the vendor documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this as a Windows service, try adding below line to `wrapper.conf`

```
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
```

Comment: I'm new to Java - can you tell me what this is doing?

Comment: If this is `true`, tomcat expects quotes in JSP attributes to be escaped. So unescaped quotes in JSP attributes will cause issues. Ref: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Jasper

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to wrapper.conf file:

```
wrapper.java.additional.18 = -Dcomponents.repo=${carbon_home}\\repository\\components
wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
```